# Jquery font family and size change inside a select list menu not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, font-family

The following code workds in Firefox but not in Chrome any suggestions?

html:

```
<select name="fontso" id="fontselect"><option selected="selected">Personalized text font</option>  <option id="dragon_font" value="dragon_is_comingregular">Dragon Is Coming</option> <option id="libre_font" value="Libre Baskerville">Baskerville </option></select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#dragon_font').click(function(){   
$('.word_preview').css('font-family', 'dragon_is_comingregular');
curSize= parseInt($('.word_preview').css('font-size'));
if(curSize==14)
$('.word_preview').css('font-size', 40);
}); 
$('#libre_font').click(function(){   
$('.word_preview').css('font-family', 'Libre Baskerville');
curSize= parseInt($('.word_preview').css('font-size'));
if(curSize>=40)
$('.word_preview').css('font-size', 14);
}); 
});
```

Comment: You cannot bind any event to OPTION element on chrome, use the select change event instead and filter regarding value

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to A. Wolff found the solution.

Here is the changed jquery code:

```
$('#fontselect').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
if(valueSelected=='dragon_is_comingregular') {
$('.word_preview').css('font-family', 'dragon_is_comingregular');
$('.word_preview').css('font-size', 40);
}
else if (valueSelected=='Libre Baskerville') {
$('.word_preview').css('font-family', 'Libre Baskerville');
$('.word_preview').css('font-size', 14);
}
});
});
```